# Why does google does not put "http://" in my website name?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I always set my domains to avoid `www` and use `http://`, however google never indexes `http://`, which means in the google results my website always shows up as `mywebsite.com` only.

```
# activate URL rewriting
RewriteEngine on

# Remove www    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mywebsite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# do not rewrite links to the documentation, assets and public files
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|images|robots\.txt)

# do not rewrite for php files in the document root, robots.txt or the maintenance page
RewriteCond $1 !^([^\..]+\.php|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml)

# but rewrite everything else
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Has the issue anything to do with my `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't force google to show http:// , google always remove it if url starts with http:// he will keep it if url starts with https://

You can control www with your htaccess file, but not http:// , and purpose of that http://mywebsite.com/$1 is not to tell him to show http:// , you must specify protocol otherwise he will act like you specified local address.

If you check urls in google results you can confirm this, google will show protocol part just if it's not http